# Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova apps: how to deploy directly to iOS local device connected to PC (not Mac)?

Tags: cordova

I am trying to deploy a simple app I build in Visual Studio 2015 for Apache Cordova to an iPhone connected to USB port of the same PC that is running Visual Studio. All the online references I see explain the setup for "remote device" using a Mac but there is a reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757056.aspx) saying

> If you are running the app on your PC (Local Device), iTunes will start and the iOS app will automatically be added to (or replaced in) your library

But this doesn't happen in my case and Visual Studio asks for setting up the "Remote Agent Configuration" in Tools > Options > Tools for Apache codova

How can I just deploy my Cordova application on iOS device connected to PC without a Mac?

Comment: Have you created a account with apple for installing a APP? As far as I know you require a valid account for installing APP on IOS device? How do you think Apple is making money :-(

Comment: I have an account with Apple but that is for Mac not PC. How do I use that account on PC in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

You still need a Mac on the network for this.  The iOS package still needs to be *built* on a Mac (notice the bullets at the top of the page you referenced):

> - iOS Simulator, which requires installation and configuration of the    vs-mda-remote agent when running from Visual Studio.
> - iOS device, **which also requires** installation and configuration of the    vs-mda-remote agent when running from Visual Studio.

The only way I'm aware of to build an iOS package without using your own Mac is through the use of [Adobe PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) which I don't think has an Visual  Studio integration.

Comment: Why do Apple have to make things so complicated?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it (planning on trying it this weekend) but it seems that VS community allowed to deploy your Cordova apps to your iPhone through iTunes. [See here](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ios/)

*Edited: Fixed a typo...*

Comment: Tried it! Still need a MAC configured with the remote agent to work. It would be so nice if this was not necessary. If someone has anything on this I would appreciate the information.